# Android Chat Application : Message Adapter does not update the items in list view correctly

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is my first question in Stack Overflow, I have been building a simple chat application on Android which loads the chat History from a online database and it will be displayed in a list view using a customised message adapter.

Here is the current state of the program:

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mnQN.jpg)

However, the layout of the list items is not correct after the 6th chat message down the array list, and all the following chat messages are repeating the layout of the first 6 messages.

Here is the code for my adapter:

```
public class messageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<chatMessage> {

private Activity activity;
private List<chatMessage> messages;

public messageAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<chatMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.activity = context;
    this.messages = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int layoutResource = 0; // determined by view type
    chatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (chatMessage.isMine()) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_right;
    } else {
        layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_left;
    }

    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("ViewID", "generated");
    }

    //set message content
    holder.message.setText(chatMessage.getContent());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // return the total number of view types. this value should never change
    // at runtime
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return a value between 0 and (getViewTypeCount - 1)
    return position % 2;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView message;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
    }
}
```

And this is the method that I load chat messages into the Array List:

```
private class getChatHistory extends AsyncTask<DBConnection,Long,JSONArray> {
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(DBConnection... params) {
        return params[0].getChatHistory(userID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        chatData = jsonArray;

        if (chatData != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chatData.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject currentItem = null;

                try
                {
                    currentItem = chatData.getJSONObject(i);
                    int msgID = currentItem.getInt("MessageID");
                    String currentText = currentItem.getString("MessageContent");
                    int senderID = currentItem.getInt("SenderID");
                    int receiverID = currentItem.getInt("ReceiverID");
                    chatMessage currentMessage = new chatMessage(currentText, senderID, userID);
                    Log.d("Is Mine", Boolean.toString(currentMessage.isMine()));
                    messageHistory.add(currentMessage);
                    DBAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the JSONArray I obtained from the PHP file that I ran:

```
[{"MessageID":"1","SenderID":"1","ReceiverID":"8","Duration":"2.4","MessageContent":"agnblean liajiaj vliwv fla","MessageLength":"26","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-04 14:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"2","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"3.1","MessageContent":"akwuehrgeubwfcofawve","MessageLength":"20","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-04 17:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"3","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"3.1","MessageContent":"akwuehrgeubwfjurawve","MessageLength":"20","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-04 17:00:05"},
{"MessageID":"4","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"3.1","MessageContent":"akwuehrgeubwalwrawve","MessageLength":"20","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-04 17:00:10"},
{"MessageID":"5","SenderID":"1","ReceiverID":"8","Duration":"3.1","MessageContent":"akwuehrgeubwalwrawve","MessageLength":"20","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-04 17:01:10"},
{"MessageID":"8","SenderID":"1","ReceiverID":"8","Duration":"4.6","MessageContent":"vsjkgkgredjegwhkaga","MessageLength":"23","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-05 05:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"9","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"5.2","MessageContent":"agrlanwligna","MessageLength":"21","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-06 00:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"10","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"7.2","MessageContent":"akewgaughurawaarg","MessageLength":"12","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-12 00:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"11","SenderID":"1","ReceiverID":"8","Duration":"7.2","MessageContent":"wgkakjrgnjange","MessageLength":"41","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-15 00:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"12","SenderID":"1","ReceiverID":"8","Duration":"4.67","MessageContent":"yikes","MessageLength":"5","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-21 00:00:00"},
{"MessageID":"13","SenderID":"8","ReceiverID":"1","Duration":"8.2","MessageContent":"iobanoine","MessageLength":"4","Status":"received","Date":"2016-04-30 00:00:00"}]
```

So I thought that this would produce the correct layout for the chat history, which the active user being user ID = 1, and all the message with sender ID = 1 should be on the right hand side of the list view, but instead I got this:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KqcM.jpg)

This is the screenshot of the 5-8th element in the list view, but the 7th element is on the right hand side instead of being on the left hand side, and the later element keep on repeating the previous 6 element's pattern. I have checked the log for the convert view and it only shows up 6 times, is that in anyway related to this error? And how do I solve this problem of the adapter not locating the list item resource correctly?

**EDIT** : I have changed the override of the getItemViewType() into this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    chatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
    if (chatMessage.isMine()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And I have also removed the override method for getViewTypeCount, and changed the condition a bit in the getView() method:

```
int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (viewType==0) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_right;
    } else {
        layoutResource = R.layout.chat_bubble_left;
    }
```

Now the chat message list is in normal order up to the 8th element, and then the order become incorrect again.

**EDIT 2**

I have trace the log for the number of list item generated (i.e. new items) and this is the result I get after scrolling down to the bottom of the list view:

```
04-06 19:23:54.894 11202-11202/com.example.user.normalinterface D/ViewID: generated
04-06 19:23:54.907 11202-11202/com.example.user.normalinterface D/ViewID: generated
04-06 19:23:54.912 11202-11202/com.example.user.normalinterface D/ViewID: generated
04-06 19:23:54.914 11202-11202/com.example.user.normalinterface D/ViewID: generated
04-06 19:23:56.850 11202-11202/com.example.user.normalinterface D/ViewID: generated
```

is this in anyway related to my problem? It seeems that all the subsequent record in the list view are repeating the pattern from the first 5 item in the list.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem, I will post my solution when I have found one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it come from the `getViewTypeCount()` method. Here you say that you have 2 different types of layout. And with the method `getItemViewType()` you say that the different types are one out of 2 messages. But you don't event use the type in the getView method.

Apparently you don't need those 2 types, so I would recommend that you just remove the 2 methods :
`getViewTypeCount()` and
`getItemViewType()`

I don't think you need them in you case.

**EDIT :** 
You actually need those method, but you overrided `getItemViewType` badly.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    chatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
    if (chatMessage.isMine()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: after I removed the two method above the records are correct up to the 8th element, and then the layout become incorrect again...

Comment: I have changed the getItemViewType() method, and also slightly altered the condition for the layout resource, but it's strange because in debug mode I have logged to see whether the condition would give me the correct resource and it works just fine. Somehow that the resource is not loaded correctly after the 8th element.

Comment: I have posted the updated adapter method and a screenshot of the current state, it's still not working properly.

Comment: From what I see on the screenshot it's correct, the 2 first messages are send by the user ID 8 and the 2 others by the user ID 1.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong screenshot, but the 11th element is incorrect when I scroll down. For message ID = 11 instead of being on the right it is on the left hand side.

Comment: I have just updated the log of the result, it seems that the adapter decided to loop through the layout of the first 5 item of my list view, is there any way that I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, but may not be relevant to this, you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter, so set up a method called refreshData in the adapter like this:

```
public void refreshData(ArrayList<yourList> data) {
    mValues.clear();
    mValues.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call from your activity:

```
mAdapter.refreshData(newData)
```

with the new data as an argument.

Also, make sure you reference the adapter class properly, so try adding to the beginning of your class:

```
private final DBAdapter mAdapter;
```

Then in getChaHistory add:

```
mAdapter = DBAdapter
```

The idea being that you have a correctly referenced handle to your adapter. Note the change to previous answer where you now call mAdapter.refreshData(newData) instead of DBAdapter.refreshData(newdata). Really I think you should pass the adapter to the class, which is what I do, but you can try this way and see how you get on?

Comment: I added the method into my adapter, but I cannot call it from my chat page class for some reason...

Comment: never mind...I am being stupid by initialising the adapter as an Array Adapter, which is not the actual adapter class that I created, what a silly mistake, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice one, at least you got there buddy! I did wonder about the messageAdapter...  :)

Comment: but the problem still exists...I also discovered that the list view are repeating the layout pattern of the first 5 items in the list, what can possibly cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This will work correctly, but won't be as fast.  It decides which layout to instantiate depending on the value if "isMine()"  If "isMine() is true then the layout which contains the right aligned TextView is instantiated.  Otherwise, the other layout is instantiated, (where the TextView is left aligned).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    if(messages.get(position).isMine()){
        item = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_bubble_right,null);
    }
    else{
        item = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_bubble_left,null);
    }
    // set the text in the view.
    ((TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.chat_text)).setText(data.get(position).getMessage());
    return item;
}
```

The chat_text id refers to the TextView within the instantiated layout.  (Both layouts contain a TextView with the id chat_text).
I used this Google IO event as a resource:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70